# Eclipse team provider plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Eclipse 3.7
There are loads of documentation on Eclipse and books but I have trouble finding a way of "navigating" through the documentation haystack to find my needle.

1. Assuming I have some basic understanding of Eclipse plugins, how
   can I quickly browse to a plugin documentation? For example I tried
   http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp and tried searching for
   "Eclipse Team Provider Plugin" or "org.eclipse.team.core" but could
   not find anything.
2. Given an eclipse plugin how do I know what
   that plugin does (what the actions are) and if possible a home page
   for it
3. I have written an eclipse plugin in 3.7 and in my Action delegate which gets called when user chooses a menu option I would like to call another Action Delegate. To be more specific, I have an action delegate and I would like to call the equivalent of Team -> Refresh action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)  If the plug-in was written by someone outside the Eclipse foundation, say Subclipse, the author(s) of the plug-in are responsible for documenting the plug-in.  Most of the time, the documentation explains the usage of the plug-in, not the technical architecture.

If the plug-in was written by the Eclipse foundation, then the documentation may or may not describe a particular feature of Eclipse.  The documentation will generally not describe the technical architecture of Eclipse.

For Eclipse technical information, you'll most often go to Platform Plug-in Developer Guide -> Reference -> API Reference in the Eclipse help.

2)  If the plug-in was written by someone outside the Eclipse foundation, Google should get you to a home page.  If the plug-in was written by the Eclipse foundation, then you'll have to search the Eclipse web site.

3)  Here's the source code for CleanDialog.  You would have to do something similar to the buttonPressed method in your code.

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * Copyright (c) 2004, 2012 IBM Corporation and others.
 * All rights reserved. This program and the accompanying materials
 * are made available under the terms of the Eclipse Public License v1.0
 * which accompanies this distribution, and is available at
 * http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html
 *
 * Contributors:
 *      IBM - Initial API and implementation
 *      Remy Chi Jian Suen <remy.suen@gmail.com>
 *          - Fix for Bug 155436 [IDE] Project>Clean dialog should not use a question-mark icon
 *      Mark Melvin <mark_melvin@amis.com>
 *******************************************************************************/
package org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.dialogs;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IncrementalProjectBuilder;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.WorkspaceJob;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IStatus;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Status;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.SubProgressMonitor;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.IDialogConstants;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.IDialogSettings;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.CheckStateChangedEvent;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.CheckboxTableViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ICheckStateListener;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerFilter;
import org.eclipse.jface.window.IShellProvider;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;
import org.eclipse.ui.actions.BuildAction;
import org.eclipse.ui.actions.GlobalBuildAction;
import org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchMessages;
import org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchPlugin;
import org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.actions.BuildUtilities;
import org.eclipse.ui.model.WorkbenchContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.ui.model.WorkbenchLabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.ui.progress.IProgressConstants2;

/**
 * Dialog that asks the user to confirm a clean operation, and to configure
 * settings in relation to the clean. Clicking ok in the dialog will perform the
 * clean operation.
 * 
 * @since 3.0
 */
public class CleanDialog extends MessageDialog {
    private class ProjectSubsetBuildAction extends BuildAction {
        private IProject[]  projectsToBuild = new IProject[0];

        public ProjectSubsetBuildAction(IShellProvider shellProvider, int type,
                IProject[] projects) {
            super(shellProvider, type);
            this.projectsToBuild = projects;
        }

        protected List getSelectedResources() {
            return Arrays.asList(this.projectsToBuild);
        }
    }

    private static final String DIALOG_SETTINGS_SECTION = "CleanDialogSettings";    //$NON-NLS-1$
    private static final String DIALOG_ORIGIN_X         = "DIALOG_X_ORIGIN";        //$NON-NLS-1$
    private static final String DIALOG_ORIGIN_Y         = "DIALOG_Y_ORIGIN";        //$NON-NLS-1$
    private static final String DIALOG_WIDTH            = "DIALOG_WIDTH";           //$NON-NLS-1$
    private static final String DIALOG_HEIGHT           = "DIALOG_HEIGHT";          //$NON-NLS-1$
    private static final String TOGGLE_SELECTED         = "TOGGLE_SELECTED";        //$NON-NLS-1$
    private static final String BUILD_NOW               = "BUILD_NOW";              //$NON-NLS-1$
    private static final String BUILD_ALL               = "BUILD_ALL";              //$NON-NLS-1$

    private Button              allButton, selectedButton, buildNowButton,
            globalBuildButton, projectBuildButton;

    private CheckboxTableViewer projectNames;

    private Object[]            selection;

    private IWorkbenchWindow    window;

    /**
     * Gets the text of the clean dialog, depending on whether the workspace is
     * currently in autobuild mode.
     * 
     * @return String the question the user will be asked.
     */
    private static String getQuestion() {
        boolean autoBuilding = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().isAutoBuilding();
        if (autoBuilding) {
            return IDEWorkbenchMessages.CleanDialog_buildCleanAuto;
        }
        return IDEWorkbenchMessages.CleanDialog_buildCleanManual;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new clean dialog.
     * 
     * @param window
     *            the window to create it in
     * @param selection
     *            the currently selected projects (may be empty)
     */
    public CleanDialog(IWorkbenchWindow window, IProject[] selection) {
        super(window.getShell(), IDEWorkbenchMessages.CleanDialog_title, null,
                getQuestion(), NONE, new String[] { IDialogConstants.OK_LABEL,
                        IDialogConstants.CANCEL_LABEL }, 0);
        this.window = window;
        this.selection = selection;
        if (this.selection == null) {
            this.selection = new Object[0];
        }
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog#buttonPressed(int)
     */
    protected void buttonPressed(int buttonId) {
        final boolean cleanAll = allButton.getSelection();
        final boolean buildAll = buildNowButton != null
                && buildNowButton.getSelection();
        final boolean globalBuild = globalBuildButton != null
                && globalBuildButton.getSelection();
        super.buttonPressed(buttonId);
        if (buttonId != IDialogConstants.OK_ID) {
            return;
        }
        // save all dirty editors
        BuildUtilities.saveEditors(null);
        // batching changes ensures that autobuild runs after cleaning
        WorkspaceJob cleanJob = new WorkspaceJob(
                cleanAll ? IDEWorkbenchMessages.CleanDialog_cleanAllTaskName
                        : IDEWorkbenchMessages.CleanDialog_cleanSelectedTaskName) {
            public boolean belongsTo(Object family) {
                return ResourcesPlugin.FAMILY_MANUAL_BUILD.equals(family);
            }

            public IStatus runInWorkspace(IProgressMonitor monitor)
                    throws CoreException {
                doClean(cleanAll, monitor);
                // see if a build was requested
                if (buildAll) {
                    // Only build what was requested
                    if (globalBuild) {
                        // start an immediate workspace build
                        GlobalBuildAction build = new GlobalBuildAction(window,
                                IncrementalProjectBuilder.INCREMENTAL_BUILD);
                        build.doBuild();
                    } else {
                        // Only build what was cleaned
                        IProject[] projects = new IProject[selection.length];
                        for (int i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
                            projects[i] = (IProject) selection[i];
                        }

                        ProjectSubsetBuildAction projectBuild = new ProjectSubsetBuildAction(
                                window,
                                IncrementalProjectBuilder.INCREMENTAL_BUILD,
                                projects);
                        projectBuild.runInBackground(ResourcesPlugin
                                .getWorkspace().getRuleFactory().buildRule());
                    }
                }
                return Status.OK_STATUS;
            }
        };
        cleanJob.setRule(ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRuleFactory()
                .buildRule());
        cleanJob.setUser(true);
        cleanJob.setProperty(IProgressConstants2.SHOW_IN_TASKBAR_ICON_PROPERTY,
                Boolean.TRUE);
        cleanJob.schedule();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog#createCustomArea(org.eclipse.
     * swt.widgets.Composite)
     */
    protected Control createCustomArea(Composite parent) {
        Composite area = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
        layout.marginWidth = layout.marginHeight = 0;
        layout.numColumns = 2;
        layout.makeColumnsEqualWidth = true;
        area.setLayout(layout);
        area.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
        SelectionListener updateEnablement = new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                updateEnablement();
            }
        };

        IDialogSettings settings = getDialogSettings(DIALOG_SETTINGS_SECTION);
        boolean selectSelectedButton = settings.getBoolean(TOGGLE_SELECTED);
        // first row
        allButton = new Button(area, SWT.RADIO);
        allButton.setText(IDEWorkbenchMessages.CleanDialog_cleanAllButton);
        allButton.setSelection(!selectSelectedButton);
        allButton.addSelectionListener(updateEnablement);
        selectedButton = new Button(area, SWT.RADIO);
        selectedButton
                .setText(IDEWorkbenchMessages.CleanDialog_cleanSelectedButton);
        selectedButton.setSelection(selectSelectedButton);
        selectedButton.addSelectionListener(updateEnablement);

        // second row
        createProjectSelectionTable(area);

        // third row
        // only prompt for immediate build if autobuild is off
        if (!ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().isAutoBuilding()) {
            buildNowButton = new Button(parent, SWT.CHECK);
            buildNowButton
                    .setText(IDEWorkbenchMessages.CleanDialog_buildNowButton);
            String buildNow = settings.get(BUILD_NOW);
            buildNowButton.setSelection(buildNow == null
                    || Boolean.valueOf(buildNow).booleanValue());
            buildNowButton.setLayoutData(new GridData(
                    GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_BEGINNING));
            buildNowButton.addSelectionListener(updateEnablement);

            globalBuildButton = new Button(parent, SWT.RADIO);
            globalBuildButton
                    .setText(IDEWorkbenchMessages.CleanDialog_globalBuildButton);
            String buildAll = settings.get(BUILD_ALL);
            globalBuildButton.setSelection(buildAll == null
                    || Boolean.valueOf(buildAll).booleanValue());
            GridData data = new GridData(GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_BEGINNING);
            data.horizontalIndent = 10;
            globalBuildButton.setLayoutData(data);
            globalBuildButton.setEnabled(buildNowButton.getSelection());

            projectBuildButton = new Button(parent, SWT.RADIO);
            projectBuildButton
                    .setText(IDEWorkbenchMessages.CleanDialog_buildSelectedProjectsButton);
            projectBuildButton.setSelection(!globalBuildButton.getSelection());
            data = new GridData(GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_BEGINNING);
            data.horizontalIndent = 10;
            projectBuildButton.setLayoutData(data);
            projectBuildButton.setEnabled(buildNowButton.getSelection());

            SelectionListener buildRadioSelected = new SelectionAdapter() {
                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                    updateBuildRadioEnablement();
                }
            };
            globalBuildButton.addSelectionListener(buildRadioSelected);
            projectBuildButton.addSelectionListener(buildRadioSelected);
        }

        return area;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.IconAndMessageDialog#createContents(org.eclipse
     * .swt.widgets.Composite)
     */
    protected Control createContents(Composite parent) {
        Control contents = super.createContents(parent);
        updateEnablement();
        return contents;
    }

    private void createProjectSelectionTable(Composite radioGroup) {
        projectNames = CheckboxTableViewer.newCheckList(radioGroup, SWT.BORDER);
        projectNames.setContentProvider(new WorkbenchContentProvider());
        projectNames.setLabelProvider(new WorkbenchLabelProvider());
        projectNames.setComparator(new ResourceComparator(
                ResourceComparator.NAME));
        projectNames.addFilter(new ViewerFilter() {
            private final IProject[]    projectHolder   = new IProject[1];

            public boolean select(Viewer viewer, Object parentElement,
                    Object element) {
                if (!(element instanceof IProject)) {
                    return false;
                }
                IProject project = (IProject) element;
                if (!project.isAccessible()) {
                    return false;
                }
                projectHolder[0] = project;
                return BuildUtilities.isEnabled(projectHolder,
                        IncrementalProjectBuilder.CLEAN_BUILD);
            }
        });
        projectNames.setInput(ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot());
        GridData data = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);
        data.horizontalSpan = 2;
        data.widthHint = IDialogConstants.ENTRY_FIELD_WIDTH;
        data.heightHint = IDialogConstants.ENTRY_FIELD_WIDTH;
        projectNames.getTable().setLayoutData(data);
        projectNames.setCheckedElements(selection);
        // table is disabled to start because all button is selected
        projectNames.getTable().setEnabled(selectedButton.getSelection());
        projectNames.addCheckStateListener(new ICheckStateListener() {
            public void checkStateChanged(CheckStateChangedEvent event) {
                selection = projectNames.getCheckedElements();
                updateEnablement();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Performs the actual clean operation.
     * 
     * @param cleanAll
     *            if <code>true</true> clean all projects
     * @param monitor
     *            The monitor that the build will report to
     * @throws CoreException
     *             thrown if there is a problem from the core builder.
     */
    protected void doClean(boolean cleanAll, IProgressMonitor monitor)
            throws CoreException {
        if (cleanAll) {
            ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().build(
                    IncrementalProjectBuilder.CLEAN_BUILD, monitor);
        } else {
            try {
                monitor.beginTask(
                        IDEWorkbenchMessages.CleanDialog_cleanSelectedTaskName,
                        selection.length);
                for (int i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
                    ((IProject) selection[i]).build(
                            IncrementalProjectBuilder.CLEAN_BUILD,
                            new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, 1));
                }
            } finally {
                monitor.done();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates the enablement of the dialog's ok button based on the current
     * choices in the dialog.
     */
    protected void updateEnablement() {
        projectNames.getTable().setEnabled(selectedButton.getSelection());
        boolean enabled = allButton.getSelection() || selection.length > 0;
        getButton(OK).setEnabled(enabled);
        if (globalBuildButton != null) {
            globalBuildButton.setEnabled(buildNowButton.getSelection());
        }
        if (projectBuildButton != null) {
            projectBuildButton.setEnabled(buildNowButton.getSelection());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates the enablement of the dialog's build selection radio buttons.
     */
    protected void updateBuildRadioEnablement() {
        projectBuildButton.setSelection(!globalBuildButton.getSelection());
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.eclipse.jface.window.Window#close()
     */
    public boolean close() {
        persistDialogSettings(getShell(), DIALOG_SETTINGS_SECTION);
        return super.close();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * org.eclipse.jface.window.Window#getInitialLocation(org.eclipse.swt.graphics
     * .Point)
     */
    protected Point getInitialLocation(Point initialSize) {
        Point p = getInitialLocation(DIALOG_SETTINGS_SECTION);
        return p != null ? p : super.getInitialLocation(initialSize);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.eclipse.jface.window.Window#getInitialSize()
     */
    protected Point getInitialSize() {
        Point p = super.getInitialSize();
        return getInitialSize(DIALOG_SETTINGS_SECTION, p);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the initial location which is persisted in the IDE Plugin dialog
     * settings under the provided dialog setttings section name. If location is
     * not persisted in the settings, the <code>null</code> is returned.
     * 
     * @param dialogSettingsSectionName
     *            The name of the dialog settings section
     * @return The initial location or <code>null</code>
     */
    public Point getInitialLocation(String dialogSettingsSectionName) {
        IDialogSettings settings = getDialogSettings(dialogSettingsSectionName);
        try {
            int x = settings.getInt(DIALOG_ORIGIN_X);
            int y = settings.getInt(DIALOG_ORIGIN_Y);
            return new Point(x, y);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    private IDialogSettings getDialogSettings(String dialogSettingsSectionName) {
        IDialogSettings settings = IDEWorkbenchPlugin.getDefault()
                .getDialogSettings();
        IDialogSettings section = settings
                .getSection(dialogSettingsSectionName);
        if (section == null) {
            section = settings.addNewSection(dialogSettingsSectionName);
        }
        return section;
    }

    /**
     * Persists the location and dimensions of the shell and other user settings
     * in the plugin's dialog settings under the provided dialog settings
     * section name
     * 
     * @param shell
     *            The shell whose geometry is to be stored
     * @param dialogSettingsSectionName
     *            The name of the dialog settings section
     */
    private void persistDialogSettings(Shell shell,
            String dialogSettingsSectionName) {
        Point shellLocation = shell.getLocation();
        Point shellSize = shell.getSize();
        IDialogSettings settings = getDialogSettings(dialogSettingsSectionName);
        settings.put(DIALOG_ORIGIN_X, shellLocation.x);
        settings.put(DIALOG_ORIGIN_Y, shellLocation.y);
        settings.put(DIALOG_WIDTH, shellSize.x);
        settings.put(DIALOG_HEIGHT, shellSize.y);

        if (buildNowButton != null) {
            settings.put(BUILD_NOW, buildNowButton.getSelection());
        }
        if (globalBuildButton != null) {
            settings.put(BUILD_ALL, globalBuildButton.getSelection());
        }
        settings.put(TOGGLE_SELECTED, selectedButton.getSelection());
    }

    /**
     * Returns the initial size which is the larger of the
     * <code>initialSize</code> or the size persisted in the IDE UI Plugin
     * dialog settings under the provided dialog setttings section name. If no
     * size is persisted in the settings, the <code>initialSize</code> is
     * returned.
     * 
     * @param initialSize
     *            The initialSize to compare against
     * @param dialogSettingsSectionName
     *            The name of the dialog settings section
     * @return the initial size
     */
    private Point getInitialSize(String dialogSettingsSectionName,
            Point initialSize) {
        IDialogSettings settings = getDialogSettings(dialogSettingsSectionName);
        try {
            int x, y;
            x = settings.getInt(DIALOG_WIDTH);
            y = settings.getInt(DIALOG_HEIGHT);
            return new Point(Math.max(x, initialSize.x), Math.max(y,
                    initialSize.y));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        }
        return initialSize;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog#isResizable()
     */
    protected boolean isResizable() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Sometimes, the only way to find out how Eclipse does something is to search the source code.  I'm working on a Swing project to make searching the Eclipse source code easier, mostly due to your question.